# PHP can't return or echo (Goutte)

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, goutte

I'm facing some difficulties with scraping data with Goutte.
I have function like:

```
public function getTitle(){
        $this->crawler->filter('script')->each(
            function ($node) {
                print $node->text();
        });
    }
```

And this will actually return what I need, but it will return it anyway, even if I don't want to echo or print on webpage. But when I try something like this:

```
public function getTitle(){
        $this->crawler->filter('script')->each(
            function ($node)  use (&$title) {
                $title = $node->text();
        });

      return $title; // or echo or print
    }
```

It's not returning anything. I tried defining $title before crawler, but no success. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If that's your controller you need to return a view with the data. A controller doesn't echo or show data.

Comment: It's not controller, but I'm calling this function in controller. This must return as json response actually, so when I run it in Postman it's showing everything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is how your problem can be solved.
You just get a variety of parameters, and you need to store each one and not override them.

```
public function getTitle(){
        $title =$this->crawler->filter('script')->each(function ($node){
                return $node->text();
        });

      var_dump($title) ;
    }
```

see:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/issues/266